# using $.getJSON to populate jstree gets stuck at loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree, populate

I am having troubles populating a div using jstree with data from a separate json file.

In order to do that I tried to get the json with **$.getJSON** (i am not sure that this is the right function to use) and I assigned the result to a variable which I use next to populate the tree, this is how i get the json file:

```
        var tree;
             tree=$.getJSON("tree_data.json",function(data){
                        tree=data;
             });
                    console.log(tree);
```

And here is the code which i use to populate the jstree div:

```
            $("#treeViewDiv").jstree({
                            "json_data" : tree,
                            "themes" : {
                                    "theme" : "apple",
                                    "dots" : true,
                                    "icons" : false
                            },
                            "plugins" : [
                                            "themes", "json_data", "ui"
                                        ]
                    }).bind("select_node.jstree", function(e, data)
                {
                    if(jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "href"))
                    {
                        window.location=jQuery.data(data.rslt.obj[0], "href");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("No href defined for this element");
                    }
                });
```

here is my **tree_data.json** file, which contains the data i am trying to populate the tree with:

```
    {
                    "data":[
                        {
                            "data" : "Search engines",
                            "children" :[
                                         {"data":{"title":"Yahoo", "icon":"./themes/file.png"},  "metadata":{"href":"http://www.yahoo.com"}},
                                         {"data":"Bing", "metadata":{"href":"http://www.bing.com"}},
                                         {"data":"Google", "children":[{"data":"Youtube", "metadata":{"href":"http://youtube.com"}},{"data":"Gmail", "metadata":{"href":"http://www.gmail.com"}},{"data":"Orkut","metadata":{"href":"http://www.orkut.com"}}], "metadata" : {"href":"http://youtube.com"}}
                                        ],
                            "state" : "open"
                        },
                        {
                            "data" : "Networking sites",
                            "children" :[
                                {"data":"Facebook", "metadata":{"href":"http://www.fb.com"}},
                                {"data":"Twitter", "metadata":{"href":"http://twitter.com"}}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
 }
```

As a result of my code i have a beginning of the jstree and only one span with "loading" text within it, so i am guessing that data has troubles to load.
here is how it looks like:

[image: result of code above]

what am i doing wrong? any ideas?
thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the entire `$("#treeViewDiv").jstree({...` bloc inside the `$.getJSON` callback

Answer (score 0):

[$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) does not return the data; the data is in the callback:

```
var tree;
$.getJSON("tree_data.json", function(data){
    tree = data;
    console.log(tree);
});
```

Try calling your plugin in place of the above `console.log`.

Comment: i do not get it what do you mean by "the data is in the callback". it seems that the tree is correctly defined.please check the image of the result i just added.

Comment: The callback is the second parameter. $.getJSON loads the url ("tree_data.json") into `data`. This data is assigned to `tree` within the callback, and not as a return value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
 console.log(tree);
```

is executed before the callback. Place  console.log(tree); in the callback function.

As such:

```
      var tree;
      tree=$.getJSON("tree_data.json",function(data){
                tree=data;
                console.log(tree);
         });
```